# Matplotlib notebook in jupyter notebook won't save

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, jupyter-notebook

I've just started using %matplotlib notebook for 3d models after taking a break, and found that I can no longer save the 3d models in jupyter notebook.

Instead, the download button just generates a png file in new webpage.

Nor do the buttons of forward to next view or back view (arrow buttons), nor the home button work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection ="3d")
colors = ["r", "b", "g"]
for col, z in zip(colors, [3,2,1]):

    xs = np.arange(20) ; ys = np.random.rand(20)

    cs = [col] * len(xs)

    ax1.bar(xs, ys, zs = z, zdir="y", color = cs, alpha = 0.8)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Anyone else had the same problem? If so, how did you remedy it? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: The navigation part of this seems to be the same independent of whether this is run in jupyter or e.g. as interactive figure from script. This is probably more of an issue with the toolbar not implementing all options a 3D plot requires. Saving the figure is a different issue. How exactly did the save button behave previously? What did change in between? Versions of jupyter, matplotlib and your browser seem be relevant here.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the jupyter or matplotlib versions. My matplotlib version is 2.0.2, and my jupyter notebook is from Anaconda 5.0.0 version. The save button use to allow me to save the image at a specific location, it didn't just automatically generate a new webpage of the image like it does now.

Comment: But, did the save button ever allow to save something other than an png image? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it did, also, don't forget, the arrow buttons for moving from one new angle of the 3D model to the next doesn't work.  So bit baffled as to why it no longer works :/

Comment: As I said, those are completely different issues, since the home,forward,backward buttons are also not working as expected in other backends, while the saving is an issue only for the notebook in a browser. May I ask again which browser you are using?

Comment: I'm using a windows with mozilla firefox.

Comment: The codeline that opens a new tab when clicking the download button seems to have been always there.Could it be that there was another button for export? There seems to have been such option in [the code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/3f42311a3ee255ba809dae9d8a4f299642c54734#diff-d67985281d9adea97b9cabb055f57e8eR119) at some point.

Comment: Seems like a known BUG: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9117